# Can you call a variable as a value in an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to get this to work, but I think the syntax is off.

How do you call a variable as a value within the array?

```
<?php

$password = "password1";

$USERS["username"] = "".$password.""; 

//would like the outcome to be: $USERS["username"] = "password1"
?>
```

Comment: The issue here is that you are duplicating your quotes. Use single quotes for the string value and double quotes to wrap the entire string. By always using double quotes, the interpreter doesn't know where your string starts and where it ends.

Comment: How does your code fail? Also, why are you concatenating the string variable with two empty strings?

Answer (score 2):

To assign a variable to an array index, simply write:

```
$USERS["username"] = $password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also read up this tutorial, its very useful and its explained very clearly. Good for your future reference. [PHP-Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)